# Navigation Drawer AsyncTask

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview, android-asynctask

I would like to expose my problem and I want to know how I could solve it.
In my application I'm using an activity, making a simple login, launching a asyncTask. At the end of this task, the user is redirected to another activity, which is the home activity of application. The latter has the task of managing a navigation drawer and its fragments. The contents of each fragment must be populated with data retrieved from a server and the navigation drawer set the default fragment F1, which is displayed after the user has logged on.
Now the problem is:

How can I recover the data necessary to populate the listView contained in fragment1?

I know how to implement an adapter for the listView, but I don't understand how to communicate the home activity with the fragment F1. My intention would be to retrieve a circular dialog (content in F1) and run it as long as the data required for the adapter have not been recovered.

Here some code:

```
public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

     private Button loginButton;    
     private ProgressDialog progressDialog;   

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 new Login().execute();
             }
         }; 
     }

        @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }

     private class Login extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

         @Override
         protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Login");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();
         }

         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            if (progessDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
           // code to retrieve data. 
        }
     }
}
```

```
public class HomeActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

   private Toolbar toolbar;
   private FragmentDrawer fragmentDrawer;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

       toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
       setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
       getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

       fragmentDrawer = (FragmentDrawer) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
       fragmentDrawer.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);
       fragmentDrawer.setDrawerListener(this);

       // Here the problem!!!
       displayView(0);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
      return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      int id = item.getItemId();

      if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
          return true;
      }

      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }

   private void displayView(int position) {
       switch (position) {
           case 0:
               Fragment fragmentOne = new FragmentOne();
               move(matchFragment);
               break;
           case 1:
               Fragment fragmentTwo = new FragmentTwo();
               move(teamFragment);
               break;
           case 2:
               Fragment fragmentThree = new FragmentThree();
               move(myTeamFragment);
               break;
           case 3:
                //other fragment....
        default:
            break;
      }
   }

   public void move (Fragment fragment) {
       if (fragment != null) {
           FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
           FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
           fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
           fragmentTransaction.commit();
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
      displayView(position);
   }
}
```

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayList<Info> infos; 
    private InfoAdapter infoAdapter;  

    public FragmentOne() {}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_match, container, false);

        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.match_list_view);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Now, where do I implement the AsyncTask to retrieve data for adapter? In fragment or the Activity?
If it were the Activity, how can I recover the elements of view of fragment?

Thanks in advance and sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your first quesiton:

> I don't understand how to communicate the home activity with the
>   fragment F1

You can pass information from HomeActivity to the Fragment through parameters passed to the Fragment's constructors. So instead of                `Fragment fragmentOne = new FragmentOne();`, you can call               `Fragment fragmentOne = new FragmentOne(A a);` where a is data you want to pass to the fragment. Of course, you need to add in the constructor with parameters to the Fragment class.

For the 2nd point:

> Now, where do I implement the AsyncTask to retrieve data for adapter? 
>   In fragment or the Activity? If it were the Activity, how can I
>   recover the elements of view of fragment?

You can put AsynchTask call inside onCreate() to load data for the listView...etc. Another option which I prefer is to use Loaders. Please see this documentation on Loaders here http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html. It also has an example.

For explanation and sample, you can follow these 4-part tutorials:
http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html.

Comment: The constructor of fragment should not be empty?

Comment: @Rick91, I do not mean that. I mean if you want to pass information from Activity to fragment , one way is to create non default constructors with some parameters. You can have empty constructor alongside with that (for whatever reason you intend to).

Comment: I can use something like this:

`public static MyFragment newInstance(int someInt) {
    MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("someInt", someInt);
    myFragment.setArguments(args);

    return myFragment;
}`

Would you be so kind as to give me an example about the loader?

Comment: What I did not understand is: after the AsyncTask of LoginActivity is finished and you see the fragmentOne, where I have to invoke the method that retrieves data necessary for listView?

Comment: That is exactly what loaders will take care of. You don't need to make a call to AsyncTask any more. If you implement LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks interface, you should create a new loader to retrieve data (from content provider, database or over the network,...) in onCreateLoader() method and populate data to your view in onLoadFinished() method. Looks for AsyncTaskLoader if you want to load data asynchronously. I have updated my answer with link to the tutorial. Hope it helps.